# Is there a way to have an array like data structure with non consecutive indices that keeps things sorted in python?

Tags: python, arrays

Consider to have a mapping of arbitrary natural numbers to satellite data. In particular consider something like the following:

```
22 => DATA_OBJ22
36 => DATA_OBJ36
50 => DATA_OBJ50
```

I'd like to be able to loop through this data while mantaining the invariant that loop through it in the order as above (or be able to obtain two list sorted based on the index 22,36,50), as in:

```
for key, value in hypothetical_array:
    print(key,value)
```

which should result in:

```
22 DATA_OBJ22
36 DATA_OBJ36
50 DATA_OBJ50
```

This idea isn't too difficult to implement with a dictionary and having the index mapped to the `DATA_OBJ` and then somehow sort based on the first element with something like `zip(*sorted(zip()) )` , however, doing that might mean that you need to actually sort the indices. The issue I have with that is that it seems silly to have to sort when we know as we add things to this hypothetical data structure what the location/position of the elements is.

Is there anything already built in array data structure in python that essentially that allows to store elements based on arbitrary indices that might not be consecutive?

Comment: You want a `pandas` `Series`.

Comment: If you are importing your data in a sorted mode you can use `collections.OrderedDict()` for preserving your items.